# linux bash, Got a error of Cannot allocate memory, despite there is enough memory, Why?

Tags: linux, shell, memory, operating-system

Sometime I got a error `-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory`, but when I run `free -m`, it shows that I have really enough memory:

             `total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        128942     107886      21055          0       1037      17665
-/+ buffers/cache:      89183      39758
Swap:            0          0          0`

Maybe it has sth. to do with `ulimit`, I run `ulimit -a`'result like this:

`core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1031505
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 99999
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1031505
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited`

Also, `lsof |wc -l`'result like this:

`14100`

I seems everything is OK, But I got a `-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory` when I am running commonds sometimes, such as `top ls du...`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/73427/cannot-fork-error-messages

Comment: `ps -eL|wc -l` shows too much threads, I got it!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your system is low on swap space. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41547/linux-running-slow-with-0-swap-left
Please click thumbs up if it helps.